# Resizing TableViewCell when TableView is in grouped mode

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I have a TableView in my application and I've created a centered label inside TableViewCell that I'm placing in the view. When TableView is in standard mode everything is ok and the label is really centered. However when I change the mode to grouped then the label is displayed slightly to the right. I suspect this is because in grouped mode the table is a bit shorter then in standard mode and since I've centered it for standard view in Interface Builder it's just being moved to the right.

I'd like to know if there's a way to automatically have centered TableViewCell label adjust it's parameters so it appears centered in grouped TableView or do I need to make it a bit shorter and move it a bit to the left manually to get what I want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution. I'm not very happy with it but it works. I just resized `TableViewCell` and it's contents to 300px width instead of default 320 and it fits ok.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the table will be initialized with a centered label, it should respond properly to future changes in width when you set its `autoresizingMask` to `UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin`. But as far as I know you can't change a table's style after creation, so I'm not sure if this approach will fix your problem.

Comment: I don't want to change table style after creation. It's just that I first created a table and cells for it in normal view and now I've decided that I prefer grouped view so I was wondering if I need to manually edit all my cells to fit the table. I'll give a shot with what you've described above. Many thanks.